# Replacing string values with mean of column in dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a data file I load and process with a pandas Dataframe. My code works, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve what I'm trying to do. My code is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file_name.data", sep="\s+", names=["A","B","Horsepower"])
df1 = df[df.Horsepower != '?']
df2 = df1["Horsepower"].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df.replace('?', df2.mean())
```

In the data itself, the Horsepower column comes with several missing values that have been replaced with '?'. The above code replaces these '?' values with the mean of the Horsepower column, excluding the '?' values.

With that established, is there a more efficient way to replace the '?' values in "Horsepower" with the mean of the "Horsepower" column?

Answer (score 2):

This will work and will convert anything that cant be converted into a number to `NaN` upon averaging.

```
df['Horsepower'] = df['Horsepower'].replace('?', 
    np.mean(pd.to_numeric(df['Horsepower'], errors='coerce')))
```

Comment: This is the direction I'd go.  However, `replace` leaves the column as `dtype` object.  I'm guessing that OP would rather the column be numeric.  `df['Horsepower'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Horsepower'], 'coerce').pipe(lambda s: s.fillna(s.mean()))`